# hierarchical (compound variable) netCDF

Tags: r

I am struggling to understand how to read compound variables in (hierarchical) netCDF files, (one of the capabilities of the new netCDF4 format), in the R system.

I am trying to read this type of files using the R package "ncdf4" but I got the error message below:

```
library("ncdf4")
sesa_wnd <- nc_open("tracks.00000.nc",write=FALSE,readunlim=FALSE)
Error in ncvar_type_to_string(rc$precint) :
  Error, unrecognized type code of variable supplied: -1
```

Is there an R package to read this type of netCDF files?

Thanks for any help you can provide.

Rgrs,

Augusto

Comment: Augusto, I have just run into the same problem. I had 3 netCDF files. Two worked flawlessly and the third threw this error... did you find a solution?

Comment: Hi CephBirk, Maybe the 3rd file had a HIERARCHICAL structure (compound netCDF4 format), these types of files cannot be read with conventional software. I found a work around by dumping the netCDF file into a plain text file (using ncdump), then reading the file with a text editor, jumping the headers and going straight to read the data. For a large number of files I developed a small python script to do that automatically, not a very elegant solution but it does the job.

Hope it helps, Augusto

Comment: Yes, I found the same issue with the compound structure. Thanks for clarifying!

Comment: Would you mind sharing the script? Maybe PM me.